# SQL Server maximum query throughput

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am selecting a large amount of data from SQL Server. I am running some experiments, and it seems like that that SQL Server only allows for query results results to be returned at a maximum rate of about 10MB/s.

I wrote a simple test in C# using Dapper that inserts data into a table with 2 columns, a primary key and a large blob. The database is running in the same machine as the code. When I select the data with a simple `SELECT` statement, I got the following results:

```
Number of rows | size of blob | time to run query
30             | 1000 KB      | 3 sec
30,000         | 1 KB         | 3 sec
100            | 1000 KB      | 10 sec
1000           | 100 KB       | 10 sec
100            | 3000 KB      | 30 sec
```

Similar results were achieved when selecting the data using SSMS.

There seems to be a linear correlation between the volume of data and the speed in which I can grab the data, but I can not find any settings to adjust the maximum speed.

Does SQL Server have limits on the maximum data throughput? Is there a way to adjust said limit?

Comment: You are probably encountering a hardware limit. Monitor: server CPU usage, server memory usage, server disk usage, client CPU usage, client memory usage, network usage.

Comment: It seems like you can eliminate at least one of these possibilities by timing your query with SSMS.

Comment: I just tested 100*1MB and 100*3MB test on SSMS, and got about the same time. I still find weird how 10MB/s is such a round number. No substantial CPU usage, or memory limits either.

Comment: SQL Server tracks the wait stats for each session.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, looks like it is stuck under "ASYNC_NETWORK_IO", I am going to do further reading.

Comment: If you have access to the SQL Server instance, perhaps you could test it from the same machine to eliminate the network, then you can test whether it is the network or network card which is constraining you.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, "database is running in the same machine as the code". There should not really be any network limits. The machine also has a NVME drive, so there should not really be any disk limits too. I am still testing around. I might try a different machine, or try directly on Azure.

Comment: `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` means it's waiting on the client to consume the rows. https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/async_network_io/

Comment: Are you or the SQL Server using 100Mbps network adapters? Is the SQL Server running in a VM guest so subject to disk I/O and network I/O bandwidth limits enforced by the VM host?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I think I finally found a possible root cause for this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/593